# How can I remove the outside of view from CardView?

Tags: android

I have the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipChildren="true"
            android:clipToPadding="true">

            <View
                android:layout_width="6dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/vertical_line_main" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And get this result:

[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7ea8.png)

I want remove view that outside of cardview.

In fact I want have a vertical line with radius. (Remove choosen by green pen)

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your linear layout , why you are not using cardview as parrent view ?

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipChildren="true"
            android:clipToPadding="true">

            <View
                android:layout_width="6dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/vertical_line_main" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```